# Inspect - network section ( please explain what is in the picture)

Tags: inspect

Please check this image and let me know why these sections are here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering to only show *XHR* requests.

Of the 32 requests that the network inspector captured, only 2  (one for `simulator` and one for `header`) are XHR requests.

Those two requests use 2.6KB of the 2.0MB total traffic the network inspector captured.

---

If you want to see a list of *all* requests, click the "All" button just to the left of "XHR".